# TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined while creating a dropdown select in react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm trying to create a dropdown select list that is dependent on it's parent list i.e Category and then a subcategory for a clothing catalogue. The plan is to then store that data in firestore but whenever i use map, I keep running into this error that tells me "Cannot read property 'map' of undefined". I've tried putting the map block in an if statement but that does'nt work either.

```
class Catalogue extends Component{
  
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state={
      prodname:'',
      prodprice:'',
      prodcat:'',
      prodsize:'',
      proddetails:'',
      selectedView:'Men'

    };

  }
  updateInput = e => {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
  }
  
  addProd = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const db = firebase.firestore();
  
    const userRef = db.collection("Users").doc("User1").set({
        prodname: this.state.prodname,
        prodprice: this.state.prodprice,
        prodcat: this.state.prodcat,
        prodsize: this.state.prodsize,
        proddetails: this.state.proddetails,
    });  
    this.setState({
        prodname:'',
        prodprice:'',
        prodcat:'',
        prodsize:'',
        proddetails:'',
        selectedView:'Men'
    });
  };

  render(){

    //==================Subcategories Code====================//
    const { selectedView } = this.state
    const VIEWS = [
      {
        name: 'Men', 
        minor: ['Shirts', 'Pants']
      }, {
        name: 'Women', 
        minor: ['Shirt', 'Skirt']
      }
    ]
    const getMajorMethod = () => {
      const view = VIEWS.filter(({name}) => name === selectedView)
      return (
        <div>
          <select>
            {view.minor.map(m => <option>{m}</option>)}
          </select>
        </div>
      )
    }

    return(
      <div id="container">
            <Form onSubmit={this.addProd}>
      <FormGroup row>
        <Label for="prod_name" sm={2}>Product Name</Label>
        <Col sm={10}>
          <Input type="text" name="prodname" id="prod_name" onChange={this.updateInput} value={this.state.prodname}/>
        </Col>
      </FormGroup>
      <FormGroup row>
        <Label for="prod_price" sm={2}>Price Rs:</Label>
        <Col sm={10}>
          <Input type="number" name="prodprice" id="prod_price" onChange={this.updateInput} value={this.state.prodprice} />
        </Col>
      </FormGroup>
      <FormGroup row>
        <Label for="prod_cat" sm={2}>Category</Label>
        <Col sm={10}>
          <Input type="select" name="prodcat" id="prod_cat" onChange={this.updateInput} value={this.state.prodcat} >
           <option disabled="disabled" value="">Select Category</option>
           <option value="Men">Men</option>
           <option value="Women">Women</option>
          </Input>
        </Col>
      </FormGroup>

      <FormGroup row>
        <Label for="prod_subcat" sm={2}>Sub Category</Label>
        <Col sm={10}>
         <select onChange={(e) => this.setState({selectedView: e.target.value})}>
          {VIEWS.map(({name}) => <option value={name}>{name}</option>)}
         </select>
        {getMajorMethod()}
        </Col>
      </FormGroup>

      <FormGroup row>
        <Label for="prod_size" sm={2}>Size</Label>
        <Col sm={10}>
          <Input type="select" name="prodsize" id="prod_size" onChange={this.updateInput} value={this.state.prodsize}>
           <option disabled="disabled" value="">Select Size</option>
           <option value="S">S</option>
           <option value="M">M</option>
           <option value="L">L</option>
           <option value="XL">XL</option>
          </Input>
        </Col>
      </FormGroup>
      <FormGroup row>
        <Label for="prod_details" sm={2}>Product Details</Label>
        <Col sm={10}>
          <Input type="textarea" name="proddetails" id="prod_details" onChange={this.updateInput} value={this.state.proddetails} />
        </Col>
      </FormGroup>
      <FormGroup check row>
        <Col sm={{ size: 10, offset: 2 }}>
          <Button>Submit</Button>
        </Col>
      </FormGroup>
    </Form>

    </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Catalogue;
```

Comment: For which map statement you are getting error?

Comment: Here {view.minor.map(m => <option>{m}</option>)}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array filter function returns an array, so `view.minor` is not valid, since `view` is an array.

You can use [array.protoype.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) instead to return the view object you want to access into and map the `minor` array of.

> The `find()` method returns the value of the first element in the
> provided array that satisfies the provided testing function.

It can return undefined if no element in the array is found, so you will want to do a null check and conditionally render the select and options only if `view` is a defined object.

```
const getMajorMethod = () => {
  const view = VIEWS.find(({name}) => name === selectedView)
  return view ? (
    <div>
      <select>
        {view.minor.map(m => <option>{m}</option>)}
      </select>
    </div>
  ) : null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because the view here `const view = VIEWS.filter(({name}) => name === selectedView)`
contains only name and not minor. So when you try to get minor here `{view.minor.map(m => <option>{m}</option>)}` from view you are getting undefined